# Can I deploy different versions of a table via SqlPackage and DacFx?

Tags: sql-server, devops, sql-server-data-tools

Is it possible to exclude or include parts of a table having to do with temporal tables to be deployed from a dacpac using dacfx?

For example, if my database project has the following tables-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1] (
    [Id]              INT                                         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]       VARCHAR (256)                               NULL,
    [LastName]        VARCHAR (256)                               NULL,
    [IsActive]        BIT                                         DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersionBegin] DATETIME2 (7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersionEnd]   DATETIME2 (7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END   DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetime2],'9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999')) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([RowVersionBegin], [RowVersionEnd])
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE=[dbo].[Table_1__TemporalHistory], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK=ON, HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD=12 DAY));
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1__TemporalHistory] (
    [Id]              INT           NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]       VARCHAR (256) NULL,
    [LastName]        VARCHAR (256) NULL,
    [IsActive]        BIT           NOT NULL,
    [RowVersionBegin] DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersionEnd]   DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL
);
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Table_1__TemporalHistory]
    ON [dbo].[Table_1__TemporalHistory]([RowVersionEnd] ASC, [RowVersionBegin] ASC);
```

On my SQL Server instance I have Database1, Database2, 3, 4...20.
Can I use DacFX at deploy time to exclude Table_1__TemporalHistory as well as exclude the following items from being deployed for Table_1 unless the database is configured to receive them? The configuration is a list of databases in another database table with a True or False flag for Temporal.

```
RowVersionBegin
RowVersionEnd
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(RowVersionBegin, RowVersionEnd)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE=[dbo].[Table_1__TemporalHistory], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK=ON, HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD=12 DAY))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you've asked for, but this is what can work. As SSDT project is just a set of files and properly structured `.sqlproj` file that is actually XML, then you can generate the whole project by some script, so it will simply take the original project and add needed modifications for temporal table. This can even be added as build contributor and will be executed on every build of main project.

I tried to implement similar scenarios (not exactly with temporary table, but the main idea is the same), however I wasn't able to implement that. It was a long time ago already, so what I remember that the only thing that probably you can control from "outside" is the deployment configuration and then you also need to add the same file twice with `Build Include` and `Build None` otherwise there is something that is not working in both projects at the same time, maybe there were some issues with the file references as well.

Personally I would generate the 2nd project. To make the life easier, I would do that something like that:

- create new project from scratch
- create copy of the sqlproj file somewhere, can be in the same folder (sqlproj_tmpl)
- add the %%%%%%PLACEHOLDER%%%%%% or any other string into the `sqlproj_tmpl` (example below)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- Default to the v11.0 targets path if the targets file for the current VS version is not found -->
    <SSDTExists Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets')">True</SSDTExists>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' != ''" Project="$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' == ''" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Schemas" />
    <Folder Include="Schemas\dbo" />
    <Folder Include="Schemas\dbo\Tables" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
  %%%%%%PLACEHOLDER%%%%%%
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

- in the main projects add something like

```sql
/* 
%%%%%%REPLACE_START%%%%%%
-- put all needed additional DDL instructions you want to add in the temporal table
%%%%%%REPLACE_END%%%%%%
*/
```

- Create a script that would takes all the needed tables from the main project and replace text properly
- If you need, you can run this script on every project build by using build contribution functionality (you can include this script as the build contributor for your main project)

Comment: Dmitrij,
I have started going down a path with of editing the .sqlproj and having 2 versions of Table_1. The .sqlproj now has these elements:
<PropertyGroup><IsTemporal Condition="'$(IsTemporal)'==''">false</IsTemporal></PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="dbo\Tables\Table_1.sql" Condition="'$(IsTemporal)' == 'false'" />
    <Build Include="dbo\Tables\Table_1__TemporalHistory.sql" Condition="'$(IsTemporal)' == 'true'" />
    <Build Include="dbo\Tables\Table_1.temporal.sql" Condition="'$(IsTemporal)' == 'true'" />
</ItemGroup>

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to toggle between IsTemporal=true and IsTemporal=false to get the non-temporal version of Table_1 vs the temporal version of Table_1 and it's accompanying history table to be visible in solution explorer. Do you have any experience with switching back and forth between two configurations and having different versions of an object or objects being visible or not based on the selected configuration?

Comment: Also, how would I go about doing the build to generate separate files(1 with, and the other without tempral)? Or would I just build once with IsTemporal=true, copy to a different folder. Then build again with IsTemporal=false?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're telling me to do.
What would the script that used build contribution functionality?
How does enable me to toggle back and forth in the solution between the version with temporal tables or without?

Comment: you will have 2 different projects. 1 for non-temporal tables, another for temporal. The only difference, that the 2nd one will be automatically generated, so you'll not need to maintain it